# Angular 1.5 compare ng-repeat $index with number

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do something very simple in Angular but can't seem to get it working. I want to use an ng-repeat and compare the $index with a number. somehow there is an error in my code, but i cannot find it. Any help will be uch appreciated. Cheers!

```
  <li ng-repeat="(key, structure) in structures">
      {{ $index }}

      <div class="row"  ngIf="{{$index}} == 1">
           <div class="col8 itemBox"></div>
           <div class="col4-odd-fix itemBox"></div>
      </div>
      <input style="display: inline-block" name="structure" type="radio" value="{{key}}" ng-model="$parent.structure" required>
           {{key}}
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, structure) in structures">
    {{ $index }}
    <div class="row" ng-if="$index === 1">
        <div class="col8 itemBox"></div>
        <div class="col4-odd-fix itemBox"></div>
    </div>
    <input style="display: inline-block" name="structure" type="radio" value="{{key}}" ng-model="$parent.structure" required> {{key}}
</li>
```

You had a couple of issues:

1. You need to use `ng-if`, `ngIf` is Angular 2 syntax.
2. You shouldn't use `{{ }}` inside `ng-if`, you just need `$index === 1`.

Comment: Thanks mate, worked like a charm. Guess I mixed angular 1 and angular 2. Anyways thanks for the pointers.